# How do I get a count of unread messages/channels/servers on Discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm planning on making a dashboard app that shows me stuff like what's on my calendar today and tasks I need to complete and how many unread messages I have in various apps, including discord. I have looked through the `discord.py` documentation and I have found the `discord.Message.ack()` method which marks a message as read, but I am not sure how to check if a message is actually read or unread. How would I go about getting the amount of unread messages from discord?

Comment: You might want to add the code you already have.

Comment: I think you need to make a self bot for that.

Comment: Only a selfbot can manage read / unread message with `channel.ack()`. If you want to use a true bot, you can work with timestamp and `channel.history`

Answer (score -1):

If doesn't fix your problem, then send the error message and I will have a look into fixing it!

```py
MessagesUnread = 0 #sets the variable to 0 (predefines etc)
for x in discord.Message.ack() #cycles through all of the messages
    MessagesUnread = MessagesUnread + 1 #finally, it adds to the variable per 
                                        #message unread!
```

Comment: Please provide explanation on your answer. Also, it's cool to tell someone you will help him more if your solution doesn't works but first present the solution then you can say those things.